# Simple collision detection three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is there a way to implement simple collision detection, preferably using ray casting

Here's a pictures of my game. The randomblock moves down the board and the paddle has to avoid it

all my objects are created by using this code:

```
paddle = new THREE.Mesh(

        new THREE.CubeGeometry(
                paddleWidth,
                paddleHeight,
                paddleDepth,
                paddleQuality,
                paddleQuality,
                paddleQuality),                                

                paddleMaterial);
```

Ive tried using the raycasting solution before but it never seems to work

[image]

Comment: If you set up a JSFiddle I'll see If I can implement raycasting.

Comment: I"m not sure if you have come across this yet but here's a great example of what your looking for. http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Collision-Detection.html

Comment: Yeah ive tried using this method, but it never seems to work and im not sure what the problem  is. I havent used JSFiddle yet though

Comment: JSFiddle lets you put your code into a live example so you can share it with others. You can also use Codepen. They both work good. If you set one up I'll see if I can get it working.

Comment: Thanks alot :) ill see if I can set it up tomorrow. I really need help with this collision problem

Comment: No problem. I should be on some time after 5pm.

Comment: [http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JgqLb](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JgqLb) here is my codepen, forgive me if my coding is terrible im still new at javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey just a few notes for yea. You should start using your browser console to check for error message's you have a few going on. if your using firefox or chrome hit CTRL + Shift + J then click console. CubeGeometry has been changed to BoxGeometry. Also I changed up your controls a bit. J and K now slide the thing back and forth. Here's the link to the new Codepen with working collision detection.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GHofz?editors=001

```
function collision() {
    var originPoint = paddle.position.clone();
    for (var vertexIndex = 0; vertexIndex < paddle.geometry.vertices.length; vertexIndex++) {   
        var ray = new THREE.Raycaster( paddle.position, paddle.geometry.vertices[vertexIndex] );
        var collisionResults = ray.intersectObjects( collidableMeshList );
        if ( collisionResults.length > 0)  {
           hit = true;
        }
    } 
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. You have saved a lot of headache :)